# runOnUiThread not functioning as intended? Android Development

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, okhttp

I am not very sure if this title is fitting of my question, but I not sure what else to title this post.

I am working on a transit tracking app which makes an HTTPS request on the click of a button, and returns an XML file containing data related to the buses (long, lat, destination, etc.) However, it does not function as I am intending it to, and (although I am not 100% certain) I feel like it may have to do with my runOnUiThread.

[Snapshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Gfc.png)

As you can see in the image of the UI, the user searches a route number, and upon clicking the "FIND" button an HTTPS request should be sent to retrieve the list of buses along with their details in an XML file. The first time a user enters a route number everything works fine, and the buses are displayed on the map as intended. But if the user wants to either search for a the locations of a new bus number or if they click the button with the same route number, the previous bus markers disappear, and a second click of the "FIND" button is needed to update the UI.

This is not what I want to happen. Ideally, the old markers should all be cleared and the new ones should immediately be added upon a single button click.

Below are code blocks of where I believe my code is going wrong. Unfortunately after much experimenting I am still unable to find out where it is going wrong exactly.

```
        // Dummy object
        var bus = Bus(0.0, 0.0, null, null)

        // Loop through XML documents and pull lat/long values
        while(event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.name == "Latitude") {
                latIsNext = true
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.name == "Longitude") {
                longIsNext = true
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.name == "Destination") {
                destIsNext = true
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.name == "Direction") {
                directionIsNext = true
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.TEXT && latIsNext) {
                bus.lat = parser.text.toDouble()
                latIsNext = false
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.TEXT && longIsNext) {
                bus.long = parser.text.toDouble()
                longIsNext = false
                // Add Bus object to list since the Longitude is the last
                // value we want to parse
                busList += bus
                bus = Bus(0.0, 0.0, null, null)
                // break
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.TEXT && destIsNext) {
                bus.dest = parser.text
                destIsNext = false
            }
            else if(event == XmlPullParser.TEXT && directionIsNext) {
                bus.direction = parser.text
                directionIsNext = false
            }
            event = parser.next()
        }
```

Note the commented break statement in the above code: when I have it uncommented, only one bus's data is parsed and the while loop is immediately exited. I used this for testing purposes and found that the app actually does work as intended when its there (but of course this is not how the app should function.)

```
runOnUiThread(object: Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                // Clear map prev map markers before adding new ones
                if(markerList.isNotEmpty()) {
                    for(m in markerList) { m.remove() }
                }
                mMap.clear()

                for(i in busList.indices) {
                    var coordinate = LatLng(busList[i].lat, busList[i].long)
                    var markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                        .position(coordinate)
                        .icon(BitmapFromVector(applicationContext, R.drawable.bus_marker))
                        .title(busList[i].dest)
                        .snippet(busList[i].direction)
                    var marker: Marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)!!
                    markerList += marker
                }
                busList.clear()
            }
        })
```

I am happy to post any more code upon request.

EDIT: Fixed it! the problem was actually when I parsed the XML files. after the first XML was parsed, I was still using the old XmlPullParserFactory's parser which had resulted in none of the next XML files being parsed. Just moved the parser assignation to the parseXML function and its all good to go!